# rstudio knitr Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

Windows7 Prof 64-bit
Rstudio Version 0.98.1091

Hello all,

I am receiving the following error when I try to use KnitR to create a PDF.

```
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" FirmsoftReportGenerator.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output
{....}
\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43
```

I have searched the forum and I found 2 references to this, and that led me to update my Rmarkdown package. However, I still receive the error.

My code consists of sourcing an R file, creating a table.
Then doing the following:

````
```{r outputSection, results="asis", echo=FALSE}

library(xtable)
print(xtable(overallSummary), comment=FALSE)


```

Total Raw Messages are: `r totalRawMessages`.
````

Any help in the right direction would be huge!
Thanks in advance

PS - The script does produce a PDF using a different CSV as a source.
The primary difference I notice with the newer source file is that one of the rownames has a space in the table I am trying to print.

PPS - When I manually replace the Row Name with spaces with "TEST1", everything works fine
rownames(overallSummary)[1] <- "TEST1"